# Blender 6D pose data generation

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, transform-orientation, matrix

I am trying to get relative pose of object ( x,y,z and rotations ) with respect to the camera. My object is placed at origin (0,0,0) World Coordinates and the camera is following a trajectory while centred on the object. The pose and translation from multiplying the transformation matrix is inaccurate for farther distances and I want to improve it. Please help me out ASAP: this is the code for getting relative pose from .npz file that stores ext_cam_matrix, and transformation matrix (obj_mat) in WC for objects: The image shows the setup of camera path, target object at 0,0,0. I am extracting the external camera matrix and trying to get the relative pose of the target (ISS) in terms of Euler rotation and translation. The code-snippet calculates Euler rotations in x,y,z. this is the error in pose reconstruction from decomposition of the transformation matrix. The red Point cloud is the GT and Blue is Observed. [image]
[image]

```
pose_c = np.matmul(ext_cam_mat, obj_mat);
alpha = np.arctan2(pose_c[2][1], pose_c[2][2]);
tmp = (pose_c[2][1] ** 2) + (pose_c[2][2] ** 2);
beta = np.arctan2(-pose_c[2][0], np.sqrt(tmp));
gamma = np.arctan2(pose_c[1][0], pose_c[0][0]);
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with "farther distances" ?

Comment: after the object is more than 80 to 100m away from the camera the orientation of Ground truth PC and with observed is not accurate. the GT point cloud is orientated using the alpha beta and gamma values

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without either a tiring back-and-forth to squeeze the rest of the relevant information or access to the input file or at least seeing part of your interface. Please edit your question to include as much information as possible. :)

Comment: I will add more details.